# How to bind custom function to model field?

Tags: django, models

Say this is my simple `models.py`

```
class Order(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    item_price = models.FloatField()
```

I'd like to have a function to calculate the total price:

```
def calc_total(self):
    return self.quantity * self.item_price
```

Now, how do I create model field `total_price` so it gets populated automatically in database? I know I can use `calc_total` method in template but I need this in db also.

Comment: define `total_price` = models.IntegerField() then on instance of Order model let us say `order_instance` call method `order_instance.cal_total()`
in `calc_total():`
         `self.total = self.quantity * self.item_price`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `save` method in your model to set the value each time the model is saved:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    item_price = models.FloatField()
    total_price = models.FloatField()

    def calc_total(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item_price

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total_price = self.calc_total()
        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```